# Testing pages with streamfields in Wagtail

Tags: testing, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I'm parsing HTML in a StreamField's richtext element via `get_context`, and want to be able to test that the context I've made contains the relevant modifications. But I'm really struggling to create a mock/stub that has a populated StreamField.

I'm looking at https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/testing.html  but need to do more than just test whether creation succeeds and the `rich_text` function etc. don't seem to output in the right format for other matters (like appending to the `body` attribute); I've had a little success with making fixtures via `dumpdata` but they're breaking other tests (presumably due to making the database inconsistent or something)

Are there any good examples out there of tests pre-populating a StreamField?

Answer (score 0):

... turns out it's remarkably simple, once it's been pointed out to you!

Once you've got your page (where `pagetype` is the module name and `PageName` the class name)

```py
from modules.pagetype.models import PageName
page = PageName()
```

add some JSON to the StreamField object (here called `body`)

```py
import json
page.body = json.dumps(
    [
       {"type": "rich_text", "value": "<h2>Hello, World!</h2>"},
       {"type": "rich_text", "value": "<h4>Here's another field</h4>"}
    ]
)
```

You may then want to then publish the post and look at the output.

```py
from django.test import Client
page.save_revision().publish()
rv = Client().get(page.url)
assert "something_about_my_output_html" in str(rv.rendered_content)
```